# How to understand variable substitution in integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, substitution

For an integral $\int^b_af(x)dx$,it i substitute $x$ with $at$, the I have ${1\over a}\int^{b\over a}_1 f(t)dt.$

What confuses me is that why would we have a $1\over a$ front. From the integral's definition point of view, we have already chop $\Delta x$ small enough, why do we have to make the $\Delta t $ $1\over a$times smaller? Is there any intuitive explanat

Comment: Hint: What's $\frac{dx}{dt}$?

Comment: If $x$ is related to $t$ by $x=at$, then a little $\Delta x$ will have the same relationship to $\Delta t$. Think about stretching your axes. Your distances change in a similar way.